# Bitbake do_fetch fails on incorrect hash

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am trying to build a system (Yocto based project) using bitbake and one of the steps is that it needs to retrieve an archive.zip file with a hex file in it from a Jenkins instance somewhere and install that somewhere within the kernel.
The problem now is that I have get a bitbake error on the do_fetch step of this precise recipe.

`File: '/cache/downloads/firmware-17.zip' has sha256 checksum 6b565bbe776e3eabd883af7d1660db6ac2c13f13f16fbb1dbf6b9af42e31e9c9 when 6b565bbe776e3eabd883af7d1660db6ac2c13f13f16fbb1dbf6b9af42e31e9c9  was expected If this change is expected (e.g. you have upgraded to a new version without updating the checksums) then you can use these lines within the recipe: SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "6b565bbe776e3eabd883af7d1660db6ac2c13f13f16fbb1dbf6b9af42e31e9c9"`

As you can see the expected checksum is identical between what bitbake reads and expects so I don't really understand what to do at the moment.

What I have already tried is:

1. Ensure that bitbake does a full clean build.
2. Bump the repository where archive.zip originates from so that the hash isn't the problem.

What I haven't tried yet is:

1. Manually download the firmware and place it in the /downloads folder of bitbake and mark the recipe as 'fetched' but since it is running in docker that is not a viable solution really.

Has anybody come across something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect there is a stray space in the value set in your recipe. The message hints at that with "9c9  was" showing a double space.